# Parse all Views for a specific Tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use a homebrewn CMS in my site. The texts in it are used by inserting an html-helper into the view:

```
<%=Html.CmsEntry("About.Title")%>
```

The entries of the CMS are stored in SQLServer. I need a way to scan all views in my project and see if all tokens are already in the database.

Is there a way to do this? I already  enter an entry into the DB at runtime, when a token is not found, but I need a way to do this without visiting each page. Maybe via reflection?

Comment: "I need a way to scan all views in my project and see if all tokens are already in the databse" - I don't quite understand this sentence.  Are you talking run-time or design-time?

Comment: Any way is acceptable. It would be ok to do designtime parsing of the aspx. But I guess its easier to do something similar to trace.axd where the controlltree is available.

Comment: I just had a look at trace.axd and saw that  my HtmlHelper does not generate an entry in the controlltree. So I guess reflection is not a possible way.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create a page (controller action) that scans through the files looking for "Html.CmsEntry" and parses out the page names, and then queries the database.

If you have access to the database from your dev machine, you could possible do this in a console app, and set it as a build action, so whenever you compile, it runs.

Failing that, you could try relying on a spider (GoogleBot, or otherwise) to hit all your pages, and trigger your existing logging code.

Alternatively, you could store all your page names as constants or enum values. If you used enum values, you could easily spin through them (using `Enum.GetValues`) and check they're in the database.

All that said, if the pages are stored in your database, can't you do away with all the static pages that call them, and generate everything dynamically from the content already in the database?